# Are squatting toilets significantly healthier then conventional toilets?

Tags: medical-science

NaturesPlatform writes in [Seven Advantages of Squatting](http://www.naturesplatform.com/health_benefits.html):

> Makes elimination faster, easier and more complete. This helps prevent "fecal stagnation," a prime factor in colon cancer, appendicitis and inflammatory bowel disease.
>
> [...]
>
> Securely seals the ileocecal valve, between the colon and the small intestine. In the conventional sitting position, this valve is unsupported and often leaks during evacuation, contaminating the small intestine.

Does squatting have those health benefits?

Comment: The title is too broad - broader than the claim. I considered narrowing the question to "causes contamination of the small intestine" but I have no idea what that means. Contaminating what with what? I considered narrowing it to colon cancer, but I think the answer to the marked duplicate question covers that. I considered narrowing it down to appendicitis or IBS, but I was afraid I was getting too far from the original question. Is there something we can do to make this different from the duplicate?